# PHP - If , else if statement when Value is detected

Tags: php, mysql

I need to detect and display my inputs when the value is detected. like for example, I select `id 1` and its `value` is `1000` then `1000` should be in the statement.

Here is my href which submits, and show the value.

```
<a href="generatecode.php?value=<?php echo htmlentities($row['value']); ?>"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
```

Here is my code which needs to detect the value .

```
<?php
           $hiddenVal = $_POST['id']; //GET THE TEXT INPUT

          if ($hiddenVal == '1000'){

          ?>
          <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['value']; ?>" name="id"> 
          <img src="images/topupcard3.jpg" width="400px" height="200px">

          <?php   }  ?>
```

If statement is not working.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, could you explain what are you trying to achieve? what should be inside the condition?

Comment: How is `$_POST['id']` sent? This `value="<?php echo $_GET['value']; ?>"` is open to XSS injections.

Comment: @MyLibary i need to display what is inside the condition but theres an error, `undefined index:id`

Comment: @MyLibary i just need to validate if the textbox is 1000 then if it is 1000 like in the database then it will display the condition

Comment: @user3783243 that is okay sir im just trying something it is not serious. tho i need to solve this problem thank you

Comment: @user3783243, the post id is  the textbox name `id`

Comment: `$hiddenVal` should be the `$_GET['value']` shouldn't it? ... or that form is submitted to itself and the provided link is unrelated?

Comment: @user3783243 idk why it did worked. but thanks sir. now, can you tell me how can I make it secure so it will not be vulnerbale to sql injections?

Comment: `sql injections` or `xss injections`? They are different injections and require different methods to handle correctly. Nothing in the question appears to be related to SQL. For XSS see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the `$_POST['id']` param of a $_GET request, I guess the param $_POST['id'] is not available since you call the page generatecode.php via an hyperlink.

please pass the value ID through the URL ($_GET) method

Try below in your hyperlink,

```
<a href="generatecode.php?value=<?php echo htmlentities($row['value']); ?>"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>

<?php
           $hiddenVal = $_GET['value']; //GET THE TEXT INPUT

          if ($hiddenVal == '1000'){

          ?>
          <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['value']; ?>" name="id"> 
          <img src="images/topupcard3.jpg" width="400px" height="200px">

          <?php   }  ?>
```

1. Click on the hyperlink with the $_GET param value
2. Check if the param value is equals to 1000 and show the image

In first step the only param available at generatecode.php is the $_GET['value'], so you have to write the validate to that GET parameter.

I assume that's your requirement.

Comment: is the id  coming from $row ?

Comment: i just need to validate if the textbox value is `1000` then the condition must be true

Comment: Nidashran still not working sir it has an error. ` Undefined index: id `

Comment: I think the issue is, when you click on the anchor tag you get the value (value) but the $_POST['id'] won't be available for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

```
                <?php if(isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] == '1000'):?>
                <input type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['value'])) ? $_GET['value'] : ""; ?>" name="id">
                <img src="images/topupcard3.jpg" width="400px" height="200px">
                <?php endif;?>
```

First You need to check the existence of id text field otherwise you will get Undefined index: id. 
You can Try this.

Comment: This should work. Can you please explain the requirements You want?

Comment: Try this answers are low value on Stackoverflow.   Always explain your solutions.